# Unity Jumping code for player not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The jump button is not working in my unity, as my player is not jumping. I followed a tutorial but it does not seem to work. Must be something wrong with my code but I cannot seem to work it out as there are no errors.

I am not sure but, I created an image in unity and placed it in canvas and named it "Fixed Joybutton", with the script Joybutton.cs, but when I run it and try to click it, it wont make my player jump. I thought the problem was the "joybutton = FindObjectOfType();" and changed it to "joybutton = GetComponent();" but still doesnt work.

This is the code for the jump button itself, Joybutton.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
```

```
{
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool Pressed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Pressed = true;
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Pressed = false;
    }
}

// and this is the code that is in my player, PlayerController.cs:

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{


    protected Joystick joystick;
    protected Joybutton joybutton;
    protected bool jump;
    public float speed;
    public Text playerDisplay;
    public Text scoreDisplay;
    public bool isFlat = true;

    private Rigidbody rb;
    public static int count = 0;

    private void Start()
    {
        joystick = FindObjectOfType<Joystick>();
        joybutton = FindObjectOfType<Joybutton>();//this is to find the object, I changed it to "joybutton = GetComponent<Joybutton>();" but still doesnt work
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    }



    private void FixedUpdate()
    {

        rb.velocity = new Vector3(joystick.Horizontal * 5f, rb.velocity.y, joystick.Vertical * 5f); // joystick to move my player, its working

        if (!jump && joybutton.Pressed)// this is for the jump, that is not working
        {
            jump = true;
            rb.velocity += Vector3.up * 10f;
        }

        if (jump && !joybutton.Pressed)
        {
            jump = false;
        }


    }


    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        GameObject gameControl = GameObject.Find("Timer");//name of my gameobject
        Loading loading = gameControl.GetComponent<Loading>();
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Pick Up"))
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            count = count + 1;
            Awake();
        }
        else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Time Boost"))
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            loading.sec += 10;
            if (loading.sec > 60)
            {
                int sec1 = loading.sec - 60;
                loading.sec = sec1;
                loading.minutes ++;
            }

            Awake();
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (DBManager.username == null)
        {
            UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
        }
        playerDisplay.text = "Player: " + DBManager.username;//display username
        scoreDisplay.text = "Score: " + count.ToString();//display score 
    }

}


//Player is moving but cannot jump. Please show me the error in my code and solution. Thank you so much.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot to unpack here.

UI Events like OnPointerDown occur on the frame cycle. FixedUpdate happens on the fixed cycle. There is a good chance that you have a very high framerate, resulting in 5-6 frames per fixed cycle. Your joybutton will only be set to "pressed" for one frame, so there is a very high chance that the joybutton triggers OnPointerUp before the jump can occur.

The quickest solution to this problem would be to not "reset" the joybutton's pressed state using OnPointerUp, and instead reset it when the jump is processed in your PlayerController. That being said, can you help me understand why these 2 scripts are separated?

Rather than set the .Pressed state to false in the JoyButton script, reset it after you consume it in your PlayerController:

```
        if (!jump && joybutton.Pressed)// this is for the jump, that is not working
        {
            jump = true;
            joybutton.Pressed = false; //Add this line of code
            rb.velocity += Vector3.up * 10f;
        }
```

Comment: Sorry but I am quite new to unity, so I followed this through a tutorial on youtube. I made two scripts because I was following the tutorial. Can you please give example code as to how to 'reset' the OnPointerUp? or should I use a different approach as to not do this way again?

Comment: I've added the example line of code to my solution. That being said, you may consider looking at Brackey's 2D movement tutorial for a best-practice character controller.

Comment: I added the line but I dont know why, it still did not work

Comment: Did you remove the OnPointerUp code from your joybutton?

Comment: oh sorry i mistyped, I checked again and it works. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

How do yo do for avoiding the player to jump twice in the air?

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector3(
                  joystick.Horizontal * 5f, rb.velocity.y, 
                  joystick.Vertical * 5f);

    if (!jump && joybutton.Pressed)
    {
        jump = true;
        rb.velocity += Vector3.up * 10f;
    }

    if (jump && !joybutton.Pressed)
    {
        jump = false;
    }
}
```